# Schematic variables as functions in isabelle?

Tags: variables, isabelle, theorem-proving

I am working on proving a lemma in predicate logic using Isabelle, and I've encountered a schematic variable in the proof state that I'm finding somewhat confusing. I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Here's the Isabelle code for the lemma:

```
lemma "(∃x. ∀y. P x y) ⟹ (∀y. ∃x. P x y)"
  apply(erule exE)
  apply(rule allI)
  apply(rule exI)
```

After running the above code, the last proof state is:

```
proof (prove)
goal (1 subgoal):
 1. ⋀x y. ∀y. P x y ⟹ P (?x4 x y) y
```

What does conclusion `P (?x4 x y) y` mean exactly? What is the use of `?x4` here and is it a function of `x` and `y`. I guess here it's supposed to return `x`, but why is it `?x4 x y` in the first place?

I tried `apply assumption` but it couldnt finish the proof, why?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, a schematic variable like `?x4` means that you may instantiate this variable at a later time in the proof—but it must be done consistently over the whole proof state.

Let us look at your example, tweaked to disambiguate between left-hand and right-hand side names for clarity:

```
lemma ‹∃xl. ∀yl. P xl yl ⟹ ∀yr. ∃xr. P xr yr›
  apply(erule exE)
  apply(rule allI)
  apply(rule exI)
-----
Proof state:
  ⋀xl yr. ∀yl. P xl yl ⟹ P (?xr4 xl yr) yr
```

`?xr4` indeed is a function of abstract type `'a ⇒ 'b ⇒ 'a` if `'a` is the type of `xl/r` and `'b` the type of `yl/r`. So, `(?xr4 xl yr)` is a function application that means that you may use `xl` and `yr` to construct your witness in the proof of `P (...) yr`.

As you've pointed out, `apply assumption` will usually help with such instantiations. It finds a fact that can be unified to the goal by more-or-less straightforward instantiations.

In your particular proof state `apply assumption` fails, because the term `∀yl. P xl yl` is different from  `P (...) yr`, no matter how we fill the hole `(...)`.

So, we first have to derive a fact that looks like the goal. For instance, we could:

```
  apply(drule spec)
-----
Proof state:
  ⋀xl yr. P xl (?yl6 xl yr) ⟹ P (?xr4 xl yr) yr
```

`spec: ∀x. ?P x ⟹ ?P ?x` used as a forward (or destruction) rule allows to push a universal quantification in a fact into a schematic variable (or, more commonly, to instantiate it directly). Here, it leads to a new schematic variable term `(?yl6 xl yr)` appearing on the left-hand side.

Now, there are clear instantiations for both: `?yl6 == λx y. y` and `?xr4 == λx y. x` make both terms evaluate to `P xl yr`. Therefore, we can close the proof here.

```
  by assumption
```